# Moving an object using three.js

Tags: three.js

I am very much new to this three.js. I want to create two cubes. I am least interested in its animation. So, i want cube 1 to move towards cube 2 without any keyboard inputs. I am also providing image for better understanding.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On possibility to animate objects, is to use [`THREE.Tween`](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/)

Create the 2 cubes:

```
var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#2020ff'});
var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);

var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#ff2020'});
var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
cube2.position.set(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Create a `Tween`, which rotates the cube and continuously restarts:

```
tweenStart = { value: 0 };
  var finish = { value: Math.PI/2 };

  cubeTween = new TWEEN.Tween(tweenStart);
  cubeTween.to(finish, 3000)

  cubeTween.onUpdate(function() {
      cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
      cube1.rotation.y = tweenStart.value;
      cube1.translateZ( 2.0 );
  });

  cubeTween.onComplete( function() {
      tweenStart.value = 0;
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          cubeTween.start();
      });
  });
  cubeTween.start();
```

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, controls, cube1, cube2, cubeTween, tweenStart;
  
  init();
  animate();
  animateCube();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 6, 0);
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();
  }

  function createModel() {

    var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#2020ff'});
    var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
    cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);

    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#ff2020'});
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
    cube2.position.set(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    scene.add(cube1);
    scene.add(cube2);

    
    tweenStart = { value: 0 };
    var finish = { value: Math.PI/2 };

    cubeTween = new TWEEN.Tween(tweenStart);
    cubeTween.to(finish, 3000)
    
    cubeTween.onUpdate(function() {
        cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        cube1.rotation.y = tweenStart.value;
        cube1.translateZ( 2.0 );
    });
    
    cubeTween.onComplete( function() {
        tweenStart.value = 0;
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            cubeTween.start();
        });
    });
    cubeTween.start();
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    TWEEN.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

Alternatively you can slightly change the position of the cube by changing the [`position`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.position) property of the cube in the `animate` function:

```
function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      if ( cube1.position.z > 0.0 ) {
          cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, cube1.position.z-0.01);
      } else if ( cube1.position.x < 2.0 ) {
          cube1.position.set(cube1.position.x+0.01, 0.0, 0.0);
      } else { 
        cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 2.0); 
      }
      render();
  }
```

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, controls, cube1, cube2, cubeTween, tweenStart;
  
  init();
  animate();
  animateCube();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 6, 0);
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();
  }

  function createModel() {

    var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#2020ff'});
    var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
    cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);

    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#ff2020'});
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
    cube2.position.set(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    scene.add(cube1);
    scene.add(cube2);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      
      if ( cube1.position.z > 0.0 ) {
          cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, cube1.position.z-0.01);
      } else if ( cube1.position.x < 2.0 ) {
          cube1.position.set(cube1.position.x+0.01, 0.0, 0.0);
      } else { 
        cube1.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 2.0); 
      }
      render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Can i get a simpler one this one looks more complicated to me. I need just two cubes and one cube going towards another.

Comment: @johnmathew There are only 2 cubes. What do you mean by simpler? This are only a few lines of code.

Comment: Hi, i have a index.js file and i do not have HTML file. I copied your code and tried to run it, but it is throwing some errors <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>. Is there a way to add <HTML> tag inside js file? And i am also getting some errors saying three is not defined. Please bare with me i am pretty new to this.

Comment: @johnmathew The code is working now. what if i need to change the course of its travelling. I mean the cube has to go straight and the take a right to reach the cube. kind of like a reverse L

Comment: @Rabbid76-  The code is working now. what if i need to change the course of its travelling. I mean the cube has to go straight and the take a right to reach the cube. kind of like a reverse L

Comment: @johnmathew See the extension to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you could do this.

It will also be easier to answer this by assuming axes and both cube's starting position.

Let's say cube1 position is:

- x: 0
- y: 0
- z: 0

Cube2 position is:

- x: 10
- y: 20
- z: 0

In the render loop, move cube1 along the y-axis until it reaches the same value as cube2 (20), then move cube1 along the x-axis until it reaches cube2 x position. So cube1 would then be sitting on top of cube2. You would need the code to move cube1 to be present, but only run when certain conditions are met.

E.g, only move in the y-axis if cube1.position.y is less than or equal to cube2.position.y

Movement speed can be increased or decreased by changing the increment value. So an update on the y-axis could look like this:

`cube1.position.y += 0.1;`

This way could be harder to manage though, as you will need to constantly check the cube1 position in relation to cube2, and because the cube needs to move in two directions this could get messy in the long-run.

You can see an example of this update in the loop concept here - https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

I would look at using an animation library such as Tween.js or Greensock which in my opinion would be much better suited. You can specify an axis to move along, the start and end position, animation duration and easing. When the animation on the y-axis is complete, you can start the animation on the x-axis.

Some useful links:

- Tween.js - http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/
- Greensock - http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/2012/05/29/greensock-three-js/